# Xamarin How to track down TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm building a Xamarin Forms app and I'm wondering how to track down what's causing this exception: `TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number`

The stack trace doesn't point to any of our code (the stack trace only says the exceptions is thrown from `UIApplication.Main`).

I just don't know *how* to track down where this exception is coming from - if I step through my code that my debug trace shows is running line-by-line, that code works fine.

This issue is only encountered the first time the app is used after it is installed, which gives me a clue, but I don't really know where to look to investigate further.

EDIT:

As requested, here's the stack trace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number.
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.ConvertValues (System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] pinfo, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:327 
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:293 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.0.0.0/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.TryGetValue (System.Object source, System.Object& value) [0x00043] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:562 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x000d4] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:131 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property) [0x0006b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:76 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Apply (System.Object newContext, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindObj, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty) [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Binding.cs:123 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.ApplyBindings (System.Boolean skipBindingContext) [0x0003b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:417 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.ApplyBindings () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:124 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object value) [0x0005a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:118 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:483 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:333 
  at Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\View.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object value) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:119 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:483 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:333 
  at Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\View.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00006] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Grid.cs:139 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object value) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:119 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:483 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:333 
  at Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\View.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Grid.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00006] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Grid.cs:139 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object value) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:119 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:483 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedView.cs:65 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:333 
  at Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\View.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ContentView.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ContentView.cs:16 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object value) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:119 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:483 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:333 
  at Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\View.cs:99 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object value) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:119 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element child, System.Object context) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:483 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:333 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Cell.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Cells\Cell.cs:118 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.BindingContextPropertyChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldvalue, System.Object newvalue) [0x0000e] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:437 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00108] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:592 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0015b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:386 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0005f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:539 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:83 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.set_BindingContext (System.Object value) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:24 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].UpdateContent (TItem content, System.Int32 index, System.Object item) [0x00000] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].CreateContent (System.Int32 index, System.Object item, System.Boolean insert) [0x00038] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].GetOrCreateContent (System.Int32 index, System.Object item) [0x00023] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x0000e] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer+ListViewDataSource.GetHeightForHeader (UIKit.UITableView tableView, System.nint section) [0x0000d] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:782 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UITableView.ReloadData () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UITableView.g.cs:792 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer.UpdateItems (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, System.Int32 section, System.Boolean resetWhenGrouped) [0x00240] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:549 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer.OnCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ListViewRenderer.cs:283 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x0000a] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnCollectionChangedGrouped (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x000e3] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, System.Boolean fixWindows) [0x00008] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList`2[TView,TItem].OnProxyCollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <7fc7c54b5e2d419395df064dc5addbb6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy.OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x0000a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:230 
  at Xamarin.Forms.ListProxy+<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<OnCollectionChanged>b__0 () [0x00018] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ListProxy.cs:203 
  at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5024/152b654a/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at Mobile.Inspections.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00002] in C:\Projects\...iOS\Main.cs:22
```

Comment: What is the full exception/stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, I've added the stack trace to the question above :).

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58002/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-catch-all-unhandled-exceptions-on-xamarin-forms try this

Comment: Thanks @ColeXia, but that's about catching unhandled exceptions - as I've got the stack trace and know what the exception is, obviously catching the exception is not my problem. Figuring out where it comes from is :)

Comment: Would you mind to share us a simple demo which can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Reproduction is going to be hard on this one... The code that throws the error looks for a "Get" Method (didn't try to completely understand how), but you might have some Custom getter/setter or a similarly named method in you binding source that interferes here.

Comment: Without any code, its hard to get to know the root cause

Comment: @Maverick Are you using `XAMLC` (the xaml compiler)? And what version of `Xamarin.Forms` is this?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, we are using `XAMLC`, I've updated to the latest version of `Xamarin.Forms` as of today, but I had the problem with the two previous versions I was using also. @ColeXia If I could reproduce this problem with a small example, that would be the answer to the question :). @Dinash there's no way I can post code, because I don't have a clue which part of my code is to blame, and I'm not going to post the source code for the entire app :)

Comment: Try wrapping `InitializeComponent()` in a **try/catch** block. If it catches anything, look if there are any inner exceptions with further clues.

Comment: Start commenting out the bindings in your app until the exception stops. My guess is that your binding is faulty. Perhaps it is binding to the wrong view or passing in the wrong parameter type. A sample of your binding code would help.

Comment: @Gandalf458 Thanks, I'll try that. If that's the issue though, it makes me wonder why the second time this code runs it doesn't hit the above issue ever again (and sometimes it never hits it).

Comment: @jstreet Which InitializeComponent? I don't know what is generating this error - that's kinda the point :).

Comment: @Maverick in the constructor of your `MainPage`.

Comment: Hey @Maverick! Can you add a link to the code-base? This exception will be near-impossible to solve without a code reproduction.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick - if this were an open source project, then I'd have included a link in the question. It is not, so showing the source isn't going to happen :). I have rolled back to an earlier version of Xamarin Forms (2.3.latest) and am no longer getting the exception though, so I might have to just stick there for now.

Comment: It would help if you can at least post the disguised code that binds data to your list view.